# Resize main content on sidebar open

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to know how to resize content when I open the sidebar using the toggle button.

When I open the sidebar main content should shift by the width of the sidebar.

Here is the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tailwind-css-and-react-forked-i9936?file=/src/App.js

Anyone please help me.